# Trouble running luarocks 2.2.0 in Windows - 'pwd' not recognized

Tags: windows, lua, luarocks

I installed luarocks in 64-bit Windows 7, and everything installed correctly, but when I try to run luarocks I get the following error:

```
'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua: ... Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\fs\win3
2\tools.lua:24: attempt to index local 'directory' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ... Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\fs\win32\tools.lua:24: in function
'command_at'
        ... Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\fs\win32\tools.lua:125: in function
 <... Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\fs\win32\tools.lua:124>
        (tail call): ?
        ... Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\fs\win32\tools.lua:147: in function
 'make_dir'
        ...am Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\luarocks\command_line.lua:30: in function
'is_writable'
        ...am Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\luarocks\command_line.lua:76: in function
'run_command'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks.lua:20: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
'"lua5.1"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong and I've scoured the internet for answers and turned up nothing.

Comment: `pwd` is a common program on Unix-like operating systems.  You appear to be using code designed specifically for Linux, but you're on Windows.

Comment: Well, I'm running the Windows version and I'm not running any special code. I get this error when I type luarocks into the command line without specifying any file or options, and its the win32 version (I just double-checked). I'll try removing it and reinstalling it just to be sure.

Comment: A `pwd` binary is supplied with LuaRocks on Windows. It should be somewhere in `tools` directory. Your file paths for the LuaRocks modules look wrong -- there should be the version (`2.2`) in there somewhere ...

Comment: Thanks. I added tools to the path and it found pwd. Now I am having other issues getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I added the tools directory to my Windows Path variable and this resolved the issue. I am still having trouble getting luarocks to work for other reasons, but I will post those issues in a separate question.